# Network is unreachable during http request in Java, but curling domain works

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, redhat

So I am trying to make a HTTP request to microsoft.com on a spring app.

I am running the jar with the following command on my red hat 7 linux server.

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://http.proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000 \
  -Dhttps.proxyHost=http://http.proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8000 \
  -D -jar Server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have echod the proxy values on the linux server and they are identical.

This is how I am making a request in Java, the print statements were to confirm the proxy was being set correctly (it was):

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("https.proxyHost"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("https.proxyPort"));

try {
    URL url = new URL("https://microsoft.com");

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.connect();
    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());

    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);
    return status;
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return 0;
```

This command shows me my firewall setup

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: eth0
sources:
services: ssh bigfix
ports: 80/tcp 8080/tcp 8080/udp 8443/tcp 443/tcp 8000/tcp
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
source-ports:
icmp-blocks: destination-unreachable echo-reply parameter-problem redirect 
router-advertisement router-solicitation source-quench time-exceeded
rich rules:
```

The error is `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable`.
Has anyone got any ideas on how to troubleshoot what is going wrong on my server?

Comment: Maybe start with running wireshark or tcpdump  to see the actual request being made from the jar. If you can curl the domain successfully from a shell, then something to do with your proxy setup is changing how the request is being made in the jar.

Comment: I have installed tcpdump, is there a command you would reccomend using? When I do tcpdump -i eth0 port 8000 and curl the domain it doesnt look like any information that makes sense to me

Comment: So it seems like the Java request my app makes is found by using sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A -vv 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420' , however curl doesnt seem to trigger it?

Comment: @CaitLANJenner I appreciate the help

Comment: That's one heck of a filter. I'm honestly not sure what it's doing, but your curl should 100% be visible to tcpdump, so I'm guessing it is being filtered out. Maybe something more generic, like tcpdump port 443, or whatever port you're interested in. Based on your issue, I'm thinking curl is using a different port than your java app.

Comment: The point of this troubleshooting of course is to identify the difference between the working curl and the not working java request. If I had to guess, I'd say curl isn't using the same proxy.

Comment: You ave an empty `-D`: `... -Dhttps.proxyPort=8000 -D -jar ...`. Is that OK by the runtime or JVM?